# jquery get function to fetch a part of response

Tags: jquery, get, response, partial

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

here get function fetches test.html and inserts in result class div.
but my requirement is to fetch only some part of test.html(ie. blah blah  ) and insert into some div of current  page.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.load` to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) page fragments

```
$.load('mypage.html #mycontainer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some text into test.html that will serve as the "boundary", and then you can use JavaScript to split it into its two parts. For example:

**test.html**

```
<div>...</div>
<input />
<label>...</label>

<!-- SPLIT HERE -->

<div>...</div>
<span>...</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    var dataArray = data.split('<!-- SPLIT HERE -->');
    $('.result').html(dataArray[0]);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```